# ::クラス名という記法

Tags: ruby

Rubyのソースで

`::クラス名`
という記法を見ました。

形から名前空間関係かと思うのですが、何でしょうか？
検索したいのですが、名称はありますか？

Comment: [What is Ruby's double-colon (::) all about?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「::」から始まるクラス/モジュールは、トップレベルのクラス/モジュールを表します。

たとえば、Hoge クラス下に String というクラスがある場合、Hoge 内のメソッドから String を参照すると Hoge::String になりますが、::String として参照するとトップレベルの String になります。

```
class Hoge
  def initialize
    p String      #=> Hoge::String
    p ::String    #=> String
  end
  class String
  end
end

Hoge.new
```

これに特別な名称があるかどうかは知りません。